# Finding $\mathbb{E}|X|$ for variance-gamma random variable

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, moments, characteristic-function

Assume $X \sim f_{X}(n,\mu, \sigma)$ is a [Variance-Gamma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance-gamma_distribution) random variable. The density function involves a modified Bessel function, therefore is not that trivial to handle.

I'm looking for $\mathbb{E}|X|$ (and, by extension, $Var(|X|)$)

Looking at this straightforwardly, it should hold that $\mathbb{E}|X| = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x dF_{|X|}$ where $F_{|X|}(t)=\mathbb{P}(|X|\leq t) = \mathbb{P}(-t \leq X \leq t)$.

Without deriving the direct expression for $F_{|X|}(t)$, can we arrive at $\mathbb{E}|X|$ through integration? Or would this be easier through characteristic functions?

Comment: The easiest way is probably to go through the mixture representation (i.e. condition, use known results for the normal distribution, then use the law of total expectation/variance).

Answer (score 1):

This is just an extended comment.

You might want to try a symbolic computation program such as *Mathematica*, *Maple*, or *MATLAB*.  Here are the results for the mean and variance using *Mathematica*.  (And maybe there is some simplification available?)

```
dist = TransformedDistribution[Abs[x], 
   x \[Distributed] VarianceGammaDistribution[\[Lambda], \[Alpha], \[Beta], 0]];
mean = Mean[dist]
```

[image: Mean]

```
var = Variance[dist]
```

[image: Variance]